# Wordpress Default Posts single page is showing 404 file not found on server

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed a fresh copy of Wordpress and I have added some posts. When I open the site all my posts are showing, but when I click on a particular page single page is showing 404 file not found on server. I have tried same from clicking view on backend and it's showing same.

I have updated everything .htaccess and permalink to post-structure but not working. Please help me to solve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does .htaccess is allowed under apache please check your apache.conf and set All to Allowoveride option for **/var/www/html** and also enable the mod_rewrite with

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

And also restart the apache.

Comment: My localhoost setting is something like localhost:8000

Answer (score 1):

Please try to disable the current theme and check it with another theme and do this same for plugins. This maybe a plugin/theme conflict issue with wordpress version. Or you can also try to debug this by changing wp-config.php file code from define('WP_DEBUG', false); to define('WP_DEBUG', true);

Comment: Bro how can see error, my error is file not found error

Comment: Hello @Rajesh, have you tried to disable theme and plugin?? Did it worked?

Answer (score 1):

1.Is this working with plain permalink option?

- Set your custom permalink structure (such as %postname%)
- Click Save
- See if your single custom post pages return 404 error pages
- If they do, go back and change permalinks back to default and save
- Now try setting the custom permalink again and save

Going back and forth has normally helped fix my errors and I’ve had a lot of success with this method.

2.Check for slug conflicts (having a page with the same slug as your post type)
3.Auto Flush Rewrite Rules (for developers)

```
// Code for themes
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'flush_rewrite_rules' );

// Code for plugins
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'flush_rewrite_rules' );
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_flush_rewrites' );
function myplugin_flush_rewrites() {
    // call your CPT registration function here (it should also be hooked into 'init')
    myplugin_custom_post_types_registration();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

Comment: Bro i have tried changing permalinks and its not working